# Remove certain characters or keywords from a TXT file in bash

Tags: bash, text, grep

I was wondering if there was a way to remove certain keywords from a text file, say I have a large file with lines saying

```
My name is John

My name is Peter

My name is Joe
```

Would there be a way to remove "*My name is*" without removing the entire line? Could this be done with `grep` somehow? I tried to find a solution but pretty much all of the ones I came across simply focus on deleting entire lines. Even if I could delete the text up until a certain column, that would fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need a text processing tool like `sed` or `awk` to do this, but not `grep`.

Try this:
`sed 's/My name is//g' file`

*EDIT*

Purpose of `grep`:

```
$ man grep | grep -A2 DESCRIPTION
DESCRIPTION
   grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a
   match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.
```

Comment: Your said, "You need a text processing tool like `sed` or `awk` to do this, but not `grep`." The answer from Cyrus shows that it can be done with `grep`. While `grep` wouldn't be my first choice, it is usable depending on the circumstances and as such I'd suggest you remove `grep` from you answer and let the rest of your answer stand on its own.

Comment: If your purpose is just to match given pattern, and _nothing_ more, than `grep` is the recommended tool. If you want more than just to `grep` something, text processing tools gives you also a possibility to `grep` and more about that. What do you do with the `grep`ed output? If the output is just for reading/stdout, than `grep` it, if not, than use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: You're missing my point. Your answer, the way it's written, makes it sound like `grep` should not be used in the context the OP is asking for while the answer from Cyrus shows it can be done and clearly contradicts your statement. As to "What do you do with the `grep`ed output?", obviously the exact same you'd have to do with your answer, as written, `sed 's/My name is//g' file`, redirect the _output_ to a new file (since you didn't use the `-i` _option_)!

Comment: @user3439894 Of course I know about the `-i` inside `sed` and that there are several ways to achieve something on a linux machine, even `grep`ing or saving/directing to a file. That's why I asked the OP, what he want to do with his output and stated that if he just want to pick something `grep` is the recommended tool.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po "My name is\K.*" file
```

Output with a leading white space:

```
 John
 Peter
 Joe
```

---

> `-P`: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression
>
> `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
>
> `\K`: Remove matched part before `\K`.

Answer (score 1):

try with one more simple grep.

```
grep -o '[^ ]*$'   Input_file
```

-o will print only matched part of line, now in regex where it will look for text from last space to till last of the line.

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution which first removes empty 
lines and then prints last field.

```
awk '!/^$/{print $NF}' file

John
Peter
Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f4 input_file
```

*GNU* `cut` features a *complement* option, used to *remove* the area specified with `-f`.  If the *input_file* had surnames such as "*My name is John Doe*", the previous code would print "*John*", and this would print "*John Doe*":

```
cut --complement -d' ' -f1-3 input_file
```

---

`cut` needs less memory, compared to other utils:

```
# these numbers will vary by *nix version and disto...
wc -c `which cut sed awk grep` | head -n -1 | sort -n
  43224 /usr/bin/cut
 109000 /bin/sed
 215360 /bin/grep
 662240 /usr/bin/awk
```